# How to get Mypy to realize that sorting two ints gives back two ints

Tags: python-3.x, int, tuples, typechecking, mypy

My code is as follows:

```py
from typing import Tuple

a: Tuple[int, int] = tuple(sorted([1, 3]))
```

Mypy tells me:

> Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[int,
>   ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int]")

What am I doing wrong? Why can't Mypy figure out that the sorted tuple will give back exactly two integers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `sorted` produces a `List[int]` which carries no information about length. As such, producing a tuple from it also has no information about the length. The number of elements simply is undefined by the types you use.

You must tell your type checker to trust you in such cases. Use `# type: ignore` or `cast` to unconditionally accept the target type as valid:

```
# ignore mismatch by annotation
a: Tuple[int, int] = tuple(sorted([1, 3]))  # type: ignore
# ignore mismatch by cast
a = cast(Tuple[int, int], tuple(sorted([1, 3])))
```

Alternatively, create a length-aware sort:

```
 def sort_pair(a: T, b: T) -> Tuple[T, T]:
     return (a, b) if a <= b else (b, a)
```

Comment: Now that I see this again, I think we might also be able to `cast` the sort to the correct type, rather than telling the type checker to ignore.

Comment: Yes, you can use a cast. Note that ``a: T = b # type: ignore`` and ``a = cast(T, b)`` are equivalent for typing (``cast`` ignores all previous type information). However, ``cast`` carries some runtime overhead.