# Why does Mypy produce this puzzling typechecking error?

Tags: python-3.x, typechecking, mypy

Why in the following does `test` not typecheck (with Mypy 0.780)?

```
from typing import Iterator, Tuple

xs: Iterator[int] = (i for i in (1,2,3))
ys: Iterator[int] = (i for i in (1,2,3))
xys: Iterator[Tuple[int,int]] = zip(*(xs,ys))

test: Tuple[int,int,int] = tuple(map(sum, xys))
```

The error message:

> error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Tuple[Union[_T, int], ...]", variable has type "Tuple[int, int, int]")

Observation: switching to `Tuple[int, ...]` removes the error.

Comment: I find this much more surprising than the failure of `test: Tuple[int,int,int] = tuple(range(3))` to typecheck (with a more understandable error message), but perhaps it is the same underlying issue: length inference.

**EDIT:**

In response to @MisterMiyagi's second comment, consider the following, which raises the same error but has clearly inferable length:

```
xss: Tuple[Tuple[int,int,int], ...] = tuple((1,2,3) for _ in range(10))
test: Tuple[int,int,int] = tuple(map(sum, zip(*xss)))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Mypy to realize that sorting two ints gives back two ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471335/how-to-get-mypy-to-realize-that-sorting-two-ints-gives-back-two-ints)

Comment: Note that ``Iterator`` has no known length. You are actively telling ``mypy`` that ``ys``, ``xs``, and ``xys`` are *arbitrary* length.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Useful.

Comment: Note that both ``map`` and ``zip`` *also*  produce an ``Iterator``. Only ``sum`` has well-defined size.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In the edited example, the size in (in principle) inferable from the type of the `xss`.

Answer (score 1):

Python's type system does not generally express item count. `Tuple` is the only exception; using [any type but `Tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) cannot express item count and thus discards such information. In short, there is no length to infer because Python's type system does not know such a thing.

In specific, both `map` and `zip` resolve to an `Iterator[...]` (e.g. [signature for map](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi#L1266)). Any previous item count information is discarded by this. The intermediate type translations can be checked with mypy's `reveal_type`:

```
xss: Iterator[Tuple[int,int,int]] = ((1,2,3) for _ in range(10))
test: Tuple[int,int,int] = tuple(map(sum, zip(*xss)))
reveal_type(zip(*xss))       # note: Revealed type is 'typing.Iterator[builtins.tuple[Any]]'
reveal_type(map(sum, *xss))  # note: Revealed type is 'typing.Iterator[Union[_T`-1, builtins.int]]'
```

---

While one could *in principle* propagate item counts across iterators, this is not reliable in general with static type checking. The underlying problem is that an arbitrary iterator is single-use: an "`n` size `Iterator`" becomes an "`n-1` size `Iterator`" after one iteration step and a "`0` size `Iterator`" after exhaustion.

Therefore, the type of a variable holding an "`n` size `Iterator`" would have to change depending on use.

```
a: Iterator[int] = iter((1, 2))
# a is "2 size Iterator"
b = tuple(a)
# a is "0 size Iterator"
c = tuple(a)
```

Comment: What is the reference for "`Tuple` will discard information on item count"?  Thanks.

Comment: @Alan The full quote is "**any type but** ``Tuple`` will discard information on item count". I've added a link to ``typing``, which does not define any length-aware type but ``Tuple``.