# Python/PyCharm typing: how to cast a list of string to a tuple of float without explicitly casting each value

Tags: python, pycharm, typing

I have a class method with the following signature:

```
def UpdateColor(self, color: Tuple[float, float, float]):
```

I'm trying to call it with arguments coming from a list of strings. I use a list comprehension to cast them to float and then cast the whole list to a tuple:

```
color = tuple([float(x) for x in args[:3]])
```

When I'm calling the method with the color variable PyCharm complains about its type:

> Expected type 'Tuple[float, float, float]' got 'Tuple[float, ...]' instead

The code analysis can't seem to be able to guess the size of the tuple.
I can fix this warning by explicitly casting each string to a float and inserting them into a tuple but it's pretty ugly and will be even worse with more parameters:

```
color = (float(args[0]), float(args[1]), float(args[2]))
```

Is there a "good" way to do what I'm trying to do?

I'm using Python 3.7.8 and PyCharm 2021.1.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Mypy to realize that sorting two ints gives back two ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471335/how-to-get-mypy-to-realize-that-sorting-two-ints-gives-back-two-ints)

Comment: Partially. I can disable type inspection for a line be adding "# noinspection PyTypeChecker" before it but would still prefer to have a solution that doesn't force me to disable type checking. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: `color = tuple(float(x) for x in args[:3])`;
`color = typing.cast(Tuple[float, float, float], color)`;  
`typing` actually does nothing to python code itself, it's just hints for developer and for IDEs, nothing more
You also can pass generator to `tuple` , instead of list comprehention;

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers (now deleted) offer a pythonic way to do what you want, but won't solve the problem of PyCharm warning you of differing dtype.

Your suggestion of `color = (float(args[0]), float(args[1]), float(args[2]))` might not be 'strictly' pythonic, but since you are hardcoding the number of arguments you need, I don't see anything wrong with it. With Python not being a statically typed language, sometimes compromises need to be made.

#### Using NamedTuple

Another nice and pythonic option would be to declare your own `NamedTuple`.

```
class YourInput(NamedTuple):
    arg1: float
    arg2: float
    arg3: float


def update_color(arg: YourInput):
    pass

args = [1, 2, 3, 4]
inp = YourInput(*map(float, args[:3]))
update_color(inp)
```

Comment: > `With Python not being a statically typed language, sometimes compromises need to be made. `

This i agree with, and i also agree that this answer addresses the question. However, i feel like code shouldn't be made worse just to make your type checker happy, the compromise should be on the type checking side of this. This current answer just writes "worse" code just to satisfy the machine.

Comment: I though about using a data class as a parameter but it feels like a lot of extra code to fix a type checking warning. I think I will live with the warning for the time being. Thank you for your input!

Comment: @ParitoshSingh I agree, but that's what he was asking. Also sometimes CICD pipelines have type checkers in place, in which case you might need to find alternative solutions. Finally, I don't necessarily agree that using a NamedTuple is always 'worse' code – in this case it's not needed, but in many other cases (especially when the input type is reused) it can increase readibility and structure.