# Can the * (unpacking) operator be typed in Python? Or any other variadic args function such that all variadic types are in the result type?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pylance

Working with type stubs, I'm wondering if it's possible to express a type in Python that allows you to type this correctly for any number of arguments:

```py
def test(*args):
  return args
```

At first glance, I came with:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
def test(*args: T) -> Tuple[T, ...]:
  return args
```

But this of course will only type correctly the first T.

Is the only possible way to write the overrides for all arities?

```py
T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')
T3 = TypeVar('T3')
T4 = TypeVar('T4')

@overload
def test(arg1: T1) -> Tuple[T1]: ...
@overload
def test(arg1: T1, arg2: T2) -> Tuple[T1, T2]: ...
@overload
def test(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3) -> Tuple[T1, T2, T3]: ...
@overload
def test(arg1: T1, arg2: T2, arg3: T3, arg4: T4) -> Tuple[T1, T2, T3, T4]: ...
# etc
def test(*args: Any) -> Tuple[Any, ...]:
  return args
```

This is not complete either, since it does not carry enough type information to type something like:

```py
x: Tuple[int, int, str] = test(*[1, 2, "4"])
```

Comment: There is no way to do this correctly for all cases – [PEP 646 exists to address this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0646/). The ``@overload`` approach is the current correct approach – your issue is that *unpacking* in ``*[1, 2, "4"]`` destroys the type information, not the packing in ``*args``.

Comment: Yes, unpacking `*[1, 2]` is maybe not the best example, but imagine this function is just a filter that delegates the actual operation on another: there should be a way to maintain the type information through the different calls.

Comment: That might be a case of [How to get Mypy to realize that sorting two ints gives back two ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471335/how-to-get-mypy-to-realize-that-sorting-two-ints-gives-back-two-ints). In essence *any* container/iterable type but ``Tuple`` destroys its size information, and *any* naive variadic function will do so as well. It's... annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can solved through `TypeVarTuple` from [PEP646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/), implemented in Python 3.11 or forward compat module [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/).

See this analog example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Callable, Generic
from typing_extensions import TypeVarTuple, Unpack  # typing_extensions only needed for Python < 3.11

Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")

class Signal(Generic[Unpack[Ts]]):
    def add_callback(self, func: Callable[[Unpack[Ts]], Any]) -> None:
        ...

    def emit(self, *args: Unpack[Ts]) -> None:
        ...

def callback(a: int, b: str) -> None:
    ...

def callback_bad(a: str) -> None:
    ...

sig: Signal[int, str] = Signal()
sig.add_callback(callback)  # Good lint
sig.add_callback(callback_bad)  # Bad lint

sig.emit(1223, "foo")  # Good lint
sig.emit("bar")  # Bad lint
```

Also see [Dynamic TypeVar for a sequence of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73454375/dynamic-typevar-for-a-sequence-of-types/73493440#73493440) for a solution.

Comment: Could you please improve your answer with a code sample for future viewers here?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: `@overload` is currently the only viable way to annotate *some* level of variance. [PEP 646 -- Variadic Generics](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0646/) will enable annotating variadics in Python 3.11 or via `typing_extensions`.

> #### [`*args` as a Type Variable Tuple](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#args-as-a-type-variable-tuple)
>
> If `*args` is annotated as a type variable tuple, however, the types of the individual arguments become the types in the type variable tuple:
>
> ```py
> Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')
>
> def args_to_tuple(*args: *Ts) -> Tuple[*Ts]: ...
>
> args_to_tuple(1, 'a')  # Inferred type is Tuple[int, str]
> ```

Note that older versions may not support the `*TS` syntax and need [`typing.Unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.Unpack) instead, which is also available via `typing_extensions`.

---

The correct approach to annotate `*args` is to decide on some level of supported "variance length", and explicitly type this using `@overload`. Notably, explicit parameters must be positional only – they must be either `__anonymous` or `positional, /`. A final catch-all variadic `@overload` handles the case of more arguments.

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Tuple, Any, overload

T = TypeVar('T')
T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')
T3 = TypeVar('T3')

# positional parameters via `, /` – Python 3.8+ only
@overload
def test(arg1: T1, /) -> Tuple[T1]: ...
# positional parameters via double underscore prefix
@overload
def test(__arg1: T1, __arg2: T2) -> Tuple[T1, T2]: ...
@overload
def test(__arg1: T1, __arg2: T2, __arg3: T3) -> Tuple[T1, T2, T3]: ...
# etc
...
# catch all variadic signature for all other cases
@overload
def test(*args: T) -> Tuple[T, ...]: ...

# implementation can use Any to simplify matching all overloads
def test(*args: Any) -> Tuple[Any, ...]:
  return args

reveal_type(test(1, 2, "three"))     # note: Revealed type is 'Tuple[builtins.int*, builtins.int*, builtins.str*]'
reveal_type(test(1, 2, "three", 4))  # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.tuple[builtins.object*]'
reveal_type(test(1, 2, 3, 4))        # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.tuple[builtins.int*]'
```

It is worth noting that while *packing* into variadic parameters can be typed, *unpacking* arguments generally cannot: Any container but `tuple` is arbitrary length – for example `List[int] = [1, 2, 3]` – and thus has no exact type information for its elements.

```py
# unpack tuple of int, int
reveal_type(test(*(1, 2,)))  # note: Revealed type is 'Tuple[builtins.int*, builtins.int*]'
# unpack list of some ints
reveal_type(test(*[1, 2,]))  # note: Revealed type is 'builtins.tuple[builtins.int*]'
```

Comment: This is because the List type does not have enough type information for its length, I'm not that interested in the list case itself, but more in the variadic args _per se_. Maybe the list example was a bit of a bad example.

Comment: But thanks for your answer! Hopefully we'll deem this *not* the accepted answer in the future once `PEP 646` gets standardized! :-)

Comment: @ssice Looks like we're finally there. ;)

Comment: Yes, it made me glad to change the Accepted answer on this! :-) Whoever this answer is still very valuable for as long as we have older Python versions lying around, thanks!