# Dynamic TypeVar for a sequence of types

Tags: python, python-typing

why is it not possible to declare a `TypeVar` as a list (sequence) of multiple types? Imagine a generic signal-emitting class that can take variable number of differently typed parameters:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class Signal(Generic[T]):
    def add_callback(self, func: Callable[[T], Any]):
        ...

    def emit(self, arg: T):
        ...

def callback(a: int):
    ...

def callback_bad(a: str):
    ...


# Fun part, works as intended
sig: Signal[int] = Signal()

sig.add_callback(callback)  # Good lint
sig.emit(1223)

sig.add_callback(callback_bad)  # Bad lint
sig.emit("I am a werewolf")
```

Now what I want to archive is a signal that emits different types, here `int, str`. I did not find anything on the desired behaviour (other then hard coding) in the Python docs. IMO, it should be possible to archive this dynamic typing behavior! There are different use cases I can imagine.

```py
# TypeVar as a list of multiple types fails
sig: Signal[int, str] = Signal()
```

Sure, one can use a `Tuple[]` but the `TypeVar` cannot be unpacked into the `*args`.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67920245/can-the-unpacking-operator-be-typed-in-python-or-any-other-variadic-args-fu

Comment: Are you looking for [TypeVarTuple](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple)? It will be added in Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the upcoming `TypeVarTuple` will let you define variadic typevars. However, for your particular use case, you can achieve what you want today (i.e. in python 3.10, or earlier versions with `typing_extensions`) using `ParamSpec` from `PEP612`:

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")

class Signal(Generic[P]):
    def add_callback(self, func: Callable[P, Any]):
        ...

    def emit(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        ...

def callback(a: int, b: str):
    ...

sig: Signal[int, str] = Signal()
sig.add_callback(callback)
sig.emit(2, "a")
```

So long as you explicitly hint `sig` with the type parameters to `Signal`, mypy will successfully flag incorrect arguments to both `add_callback` and `emit`.

Comment: `ParamSpec` does not work with Generics. Tested on Python 3.8 w `typing_extensions`

Comment: @n1nj4: I tested this exact example (with imports from typing) on mypy 0.971, python 3.10 and it works perfectly. PEP612 also explicitly defines how `ParamSpec` works with `Generic`.

Comment: I checked with pyright in vscode and linting failed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using a `TypeVarTuple`, thanks @mechanic-pig. Here is the working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Any, Callable, Generic
from typing_extensions import TypeVarTuple, Unpack  # typing_extensions only needed for Python < 3.11

Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")

class Signal(Generic[Unpack[Ts]]):
    def add_callback(self, func: Callable[[Unpack[Ts]], Any]) -> None:
        ...

    def emit(self, *args: Unpack[Ts]) -> None:
        ...

def callback(a: int, b: str) -> None:
    ...

def callback_bad(a: str) -> None:
    ...

sig: Signal[int, str] = Signal()
sig.add_callback(callback)  # Good lint
sig.add_callback(callback_bad)  # Bad lint

sig.emit(1223, "foo")  # Good lint
sig.emit("bar")  # Bad lint
```